# Stopping the jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

I am using the cycle jquery plugin. I have a few images that fade in and out and would like it to stop on the last image at the end of the cycle. Does anyone know a good way to do this? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slideshow').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
  timeout: 1000,
  speed:  500
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/nowrap2.html

I think this will answer your question.
There are a lot of nice examples like this one on the API site of the cycle plugin.

They say: `nowrap: 1`

Comment: Ahhh, just what I was trying to find! You have brought joy to my day.

Comment: API's are so handy ;) You only had to check all the [options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) that cycle has to offer.